# Agarrar valor de una url

Tags: bash, curl

Estoy intentando hacer en bash un script con el que pueda obtener un valor de una URL. Por ejemplo, en esta url hay parte que dice "percent", lo que necesito es agarrar ese numero.

Sinceramente no tengo mucha experiencia en bash, así que cualquier ayuda es bien recibida.

Esto es lo que tengo en mi script:

```
#!/bin/bash 
content=$(curl -L url) 
echo $content
```

Me devuelve la siguiente cadena:

```
{"percent":"13.29471501108489","count":1859}
```

Necesito extraer el valor de `percent`.

Comment: Hola Cristian bienvenido a SOes, ¿podrías poner un ejemplo de la URL y lo que deseas obtener exactamente?

Comment: si, la url me devuelve, entre otra información, esto: {"percent":"13.29471501108489","count":1859} lo que me gustaria hacer, seria poder agarrar ese numero de percent, para hacer un check en Nagios en base a ese numero

Comment: Sigon sin entender, te refieres a que es un servicio Web que al ingresar te devuelve esa información?

Comment: si, es una pagina web que solo devuelve informacion, entre ella, eso que puse arriba, no tiene nada, solamente una linea con datos,

Comment: ¿cuál es la URL de la página Web?, ¿es pública?, ¿cómo estás obteniendo la URL en tu script?

Comment: no, no es publica, es una pagina interna de la empresa donde trabajo, lo que arme (muy basico) es esto: -- #!/bin/bash

content=$(curl -L http://url)
echo $content  --

para guardar el contenido en una variable, me faltaria poder sacar el valor, o algo asi imagino

Comment: Cristian es importante comentar que usas Curl!, lo agrego al tag.

Comment: perdon! jaja, estoy recien aprendiendo a usar bash, y me dio curiosidad como hacer esto, gracias!

Answer (score 2):

¿Qué tal con un poquito de Python?

Desde la terminal:

```
$ echo '{"percent": "13.29471501108489", "count": 1859}' | python -c "import json, sys; print json.load(sys.stdin)['percent']"
13.29471501108489
```

En tu script sería:

```
#!/bin/bash 
content=$(curl -L url) 
echo $content | python -c "import json, sys; print json.load(sys.stdin)['percent']"
```

Si el script se llama, por ejemplo, `percent.sh` el resultado sería:

```
$ bash percent.sh
13.29471501108489
```

No necesitas nada más, la opción `-c` de Python te permite ejecutar código desde texto. Luego, simplemente estoy usando la librería `json` para parsear la cadena y convertirla en un diccionario y la librería `sys` para leer desde el STDIN:

```
import json, sys;
```

Finalmente solo imprimo la llave `percent` del diccionario que ha sido creado, todo esto en una misma sentencia:

```
print json.load(sys.stdin)['percent']
```

Comment: Gracas por la respuesta! te comento, me esta dando este error

File "<string>", line 1
    import json, sys; print json.load(sys.stdin) ['percent']
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent

ahora estoy buscando a ver que puede ser.

Comment: @CristianSanchez mmmm es raro ya que no debería haber indentación porque todo es en la misma línea

Comment: por lo que entendi del error, me dice que no esta definido en ningun lado la variable "percent", ahora estoy buscando un poco de mas info

Comment: @CristianSanchez dice que es un error de indentación pero no tendría que haberla porque cada sentencia es de una sola línea

Comment: @César: ese error aparece si hay espacios/tabuladores antes de `import`.

Answer (score 1):

Puedes usar `jq`, en tu ejemplo sería algo así:

```
#! /bin/bash
content="{\"percent\":\"13.29471501108489\",\"count\":1859}"
echo $content
```

Esto sólo ha sido para generar la misma respuesta que genera el `curl`, ahora extraigamos el valor:

```
percentValue=$(echo $content | jq ".[\"percent\"]")
echo $percentValue
```

Con esto obtendrás el resultado que deseas:

```
"13.29471501108489"
```

Si quisieras el valor sin comillas puedes agregar la sentencia `tr:

```
percentValue=$(echo $content | jq .[\"percent\"] | tr -d '"')
```

**Acá el ejemplo completo:**

```
#! /bin/bash
content="{\"percent\":\"13.29471501108489\",\"count\":1859}"
echo $content
percentValue=$(echo $content | jq ".[\"percent\"]")
echo $percentValue
```

**Ahora un ejemplo completo con `curl`:**

```
#!/bin/bash 
content=$(curl -L url) 
echo $content
percentValue=$(echo $content | jq ".[\"percent\"]")
echo $percentValue
```

Para instalar `jq` puedes guiarte [acá](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/download/), pero si estás en OSX es tan fácil como:

```
brew install jq
```

En Ubuntu sería así:

```
sudo apt-get install jq
```

Answer (score 1):

Perl incluye el módulo JSON::PP (desde Perl 5.14) para tratar con JSON:

```
echo $content | perl -MJSON::PP -0777 -e 'print decode_json(<>)->{"percent"}'
```

JSON::PP es una implementación de JSON en Perl. En CPAN está disponible el módulo JSON::XS, que implementa la misma interfaz que JSON::PP, pero centrándose en la corrección y la velocidad (está escrito en C).

Answer (score 1):

Bueno, les comento un poco, al final lo hice de esta forma:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import requests
from sys import exit

threshold = 8
r = requests.get('url') 
rj = r.json()
print rj['data']['percent']
if rj['data']['percent'] > threshold:  print 1
else:  print 0
```

asi, me funciona bien, si supera el threshold, tira 1, si no, 0, ahora solo tengo que ver como integrarlo a nagios!

Gracias por la ayuda de todos!

Answer (score 0):

Abre la terminal y ejecuta esto:

```
~ $ curl -I https://google.com && echo " Show document info only "
```

Con una salida:

```
HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Referrer-Policy: no-referrer
Location: https://www.google.co.ve/?gfe_rd=cr&dcr=0&ei=gIauWsiRGu2FX9_yp6AM
Content-Length: 270
Date: Sun, 18 Mar 2018 15:32:16 GMT
Alt-Svc: hq=":443"; ma=2592000; quic=51303431; quic=51303339; quic=51303335,quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="41,39,35"
```

si se quiere obtener un espesifico dato de la salida por ejemplo el Content-Type ejecuta lo siguiente:

```
echo $(curl -I https://google.com 2>/dev/null | grep "Content-Type" | head -1 | cut -d":" -f2)
```

Y obtendras una salida:

```
text/html; charset=UTF-8
```

Ahora creando un script para esto;

```
~ $ echo '#!/bin/bash'>$PWD'/script.sh' && chmod a+x $PWD'/script.sh'
~ $ echo "open nano to edit the script" && nano $PWD'/script.sh'
```

Agrega y guarda esto:

```
#!/bin/bash 

URL_BASE='https://google.com'
REMOVE=':'

result=$(curl -I $URL_BASE 2>/dev/null | grep "$@" | head -1 | cut -d"$REMOVE" -f2)

echo $result
```

Bien ya tenemos el script nos queda solo ejecutar y ver el resultado:

```
~ $ ./script.sh Content-Type
~ $ $PWD/./script.sh Location
~ $ sh $PWD/./script.sh Date
~ $ bash $PWD/./script.sh Cache-Control
```